# Start a VPN connection with PPTP protocol on command line

Tags: opensuse, vpn, pptp

I'm trying to setup a VPN connection on OpenSUSE Leap 42.2, with the following command:

```
me@linux-box:~> sudo pptpsetup --create TUNNEL --server 172.16.100.2 --username 444182 --password 255553 --start
```

But I'm receiving the following error message:

```
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/5
anon warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:329]: connect: Connection refused
anon fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:127]: Could not open control connection to 172.16.100.2
anon fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:479]: Call manager exited with error 256
Script pptp 172.16.100.2 --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 17988), status = 0x1
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
```

Also, when trying to start the VPN with:

```
pppd call TUNNEL debug nodetach
```

I receive the same error message. Also, when I turn off my **firewall**, I receive the same error message. I wonder if anybody knows how to resolve it.

Comment: support for PPPT servers is being discontinued in a lot of operating systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I realized that the PPTP was disabled on MikroTik v6.25, i.e. IP address 172.16.100.2, that's why I couldn't connect to the VPN server.

After enabling the PPTP on MikroTik, I'm able to connect to the server like this:

```
me@linux-box:~> sudo pppd call TUNNEL debug nodetach
using channel 15
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/5
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xa905bd9b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xa905bd9b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xa905bd9b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xa905bd9b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xa905bd9b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xa905bd9b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
```